# Read only appears like disable control in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am new to CRM, and I have run into a requirement where I have to show some controls (textbox, option set, etc) and custom entities (sub - grid) as readonly. But, when I made them readonly, they appears like disabled and are getting grayed out. Is there any way to make them only read only not look like disabled?

Please suggest.

Thanks,

Ashfaq.

Answer (score 1):

in CRM read-only means fields are greyed out but still they are readable.

If you want to make the fields visible as normal but don't want them to be editable by  the user, you need to write JavaScipt for that.

Take the following steps.

**1. Make the fields editable.**

**2. On form's OnSave Event, call the following method to prevent the attributes to be saved.**

```
function PreventSave() 
{
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute(“CRMFieldName”).setSubmitMode(“never”);
}
```

It will not grey out the fields and still prevent the user to change their values.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: This could be very confusing to the user, as they are able to make changes to the attributes in the form and click the save button, but they get no feedback that those values were not updated. But it does meet the requirements presented by the question. I think the answer writer should advise against doing this just for UX reasons, but it is a good way to meet the requirements as presented.

Answer (score 0):

For text fields, there is one type of text field that when set to readonly does not look like it is disabled. Off the top of my head I can't remember which type. For the other field types I have not found a way to not have them look disabled when made readonly.

Other option is not to use form fields but show the data you need to be readonly (and not grayed out) in a web resource (HTML/SL/etc). Be aware tho that if your users are using outlook with crm addin, there are limitations here when the record is viewed in the outlook reading pane.

Only other option I can think of is to not set the fields as readonly but control any field data changes with javascript.

In short, I haven't found a good way to do what you need.